# res.render showing html source after rendering an ejs file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I had setup an express app with EJS view engine. When I run the page it shows me the whole html on the browser while it should show the page. Below is the code

viewusers EJS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

View User route

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('viewusers', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

In app.js

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

When i run the page it shows view user whole html on browser, it should show only
welcome to Express

Comment: try to alter `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` to `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');`, and certificate viewusers is named viewusers.ejs

Comment: @LucasCosta, what do you mean by this line "and certificate viewusers is named viewusers.ejs"

Comment: `res.render` will search for file with ejs extension.